# Django load template tags with if else conditions

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

The problem seems very simple, yet I can't fix it.

Look at below two examples. Both give me TemplateSyntaxError.(separately)
While only one should give an error.

## Why is that?

(there is no template tag called aa)

You can check this by putting one at a time into the template.

it seems Django `load` template tag runs wherever it was put(except comment tag) .

```
{% if "4" == "3" %}

{% else %}

  {% load aa %}


{% endif %}
```

```
{% if "4" == "3" %}

  {% load aa %}

{% else %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can not load conditionally: loading is always done at the top of the template.

Comment: Why is that happen?

Comment: Is there a way to conditionally load?

Comment: (this question was raised in relation to another stackoverflow question) I searched the whole internet and could not find why you can't  conditionally load template tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Look at below two examples. Both give me TemplateSyntaxError.(separately) While only one should give an error.

Django does *not* look at the context for [**`{% load … %}`** template tags <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#load). It will load these regardless of the path. Indeed, both these templates:

```
{% if True %}
    {% load static %}
{% endif %}
{% static "bla" %}
```

and:

```
{% if False %}
    {% load static %}
{% endif %}
{% static "bla" %}
```

work, even though one would expect that only the first one would succeed, since `{% if False %}` fails.

So Django's template languages compiles to a tree, but an `if` statement does not works as a full if-then-else block: since a `{% load … %}` template tag passes, it will load the library and export the items in the remainder of the file, a bit like in C++ the `#define` directive does not care if it was defined in an `if(condition)` block. You could thus essentially see it as the parser that *first* looks for load items, and then for `if`-`then`-`else`s.

The `{% load … %}` template tags are looked for *before* rendering the template tag, that makes perfect sense: Django compiles a template into a syntax tree where the `{% foo %}` nodes translate into `FooNode`s. So it has to know when it *loads* the template where it can find *foo*, not when it *renders* the template, since the same template can be rendered over and over again.

Regardless, you should not load template libraries conditionally, it makes the codepaths unpredictable and prone to errors. Just load the items at the top of the template.